# Plesk 17 Changing/adding httpdocs for website update

Tags: php, laravel, plesk-onyx

Sometimes I 'll do a major update on a website by creating an extra directory in the root of the subscription like httpdocs2 (Standard is httpdocs). Then I upload the new website to this directory, add a tempaorary domain (just for testing) to this subscription with httpdocs2 as the documentroot.

So far so good. After testing I change the original domain itself to httpdocs2. After that the website is working well but when I am trying to write to a folder (this is thumbnail generating code) I get:

```
Can't write image data to path (/var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/httpdocs2/public/_files/.thumbs/image.jpg)
```

It works perfectly on the original httpdocs so it has something to do with permissions.

(_files and underlying folders have 777 permissions)

Comment: did you compare permissions? for example: # namei -om  /var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/httpdocs2/public/_files/.thumbs/image.jpg and # namei -om  /var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/httpdocs/public/_files/.thumbs/image.jpg . From Plesk side location of doc root does not matter.

Comment: I did and they were the same. Now I am not sure about ownership. Could that have something to do with it? I created the httpdocs directory in the filemanager of plesk.

Comment: Permissions and ownership's should bed the same for both directories.